# PHP gmdate() with Daylight Savings

Tags: php, time, phpmailer

Im making a PHP webapp that will monitor a list of webpages and email someone if a site goes down. In the body of the email I'm trying to display the time and am currently using :

```
gmdate("d-m-Y H:i", time())
```

This is displaying the time in the format I want (03:14:39 PM) but it is an hour behind the current GMT +1. I have read a few documentation articles that say to add O or I to add the daylight savings difference but these didn't work.

Comment: What do you thing `gmdate()` does? Clue the `gm` in the function name

Comment: PS, you don't need the time() argument..... it defaults to now.... reading the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) for the function might prove enlightening

Comment: You're basically asking why GMT is an hour behind GMT +1 ... O_o ... take a look at DateTime instead : http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to set your timezone http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

and use date()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
date("d-m-Y H:i", time())
```